# ScanImage Legal size settings

Tags: scanner

I have been trying to setup ScanImage to scan legal size paper via the ADF without success. I thought I could just change the X and Y coordinates of the ScanImage command, however that does not work.  I have tried other settings all with no success.  What I am missing?

The command I'm using is:

```
 scanimage -d $SCANBD_DEVICE -y 355.6 -x 215.9 --batch --format=tiff --mode Lineart --resolution 300 --source="ADF Duplex"
```

Syslog reports accurate settings, but shows that scanimage changes the scan area

```
Nov 27 20:03:33 PiScanner scanbd: /usr/local/etc/scanbd/scan.sh: ************* Now Scanning LEGAL Size (Option 3 )on device fujitsu:fi-4220C2dj:100742 ***************
Nov 27 20:03:33 PiScanner scan.sh: scanimage: rounded value of br-x from 215.9 to 215.872
Nov 27 20:03:33 PiScanner scan.sh: scanimage: rounded value of br-y from 355.6 to 279.364
Nov 27 20:03:33 PiScanner scan.sh: Scanning -1 pages, incrementing by 1, numbering from 1
```

Comment: check with `scanimage --help -d $SCANBD_DEVICE` the range of values allowed. eg it might say `-y 0..279mm` which limits you to 279 mm.

Comment: Find it hard to believe there is  limitation on page length with the utility, especially  with all know paper sizes in the world, Letter, Legal, A, Etc.....

Comment: The limit is imposed by the backend, ie the scanner. See the `man scanimage` part beginning *To see the options for a device named dev...*, 
and the man page for the type of scanner you have, eg `man sane-hp` for hp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this! - it appears that the order of options on the command line matter. the --source="ADF Duplex" option MUST appear first on the line as this is the first option listed.

this in turns enables **--Page-with** and **--Page Height** options allowing one to set legal size paper for scanning. the correct command line sintax is

```
scanimage --source="ADF Duplex" -d $SCANBD_DEVICE --page-width 215.9 --page-height 355.6 -y 355.6 -x 215.9 --batch --format=tiff --mode Lineart --resolution 300
```